# httpError with f:ajax (JSF)

Tags: jsf-2

Due to some requirement change I bypassed existing Log-in page and direct very fist request to my home.xhtml page. After done that change and try execute some **f:ajax** function as,

```
<h:commandLink value="Display">
  <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render="@all" listener="#{homeController.loadDetailTail(completeTrail.trailInfo.trailId)}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

then I got following httpError. But it will fixed when I did code revert (Log-in page will direct to home.xhtml page) or direct very fist request to some other jsf page and from that page navigate to home.xhtml page.

This issue was appear on Widows 7 with FireFox and Chrome. But it seems not produce on Fedora 16 with with FireFox :(. Can any one please help me to resolve this issue. 
Thanks.

> **httpError**: The Http Transport returned a 0 status code.  This is
>   usually the result of mixing ajax and full requests.  This is usually
>   undesired, for both performance and data integrity reasons.

Comment: Apparently you're also redirecting the ajax request. Show the code behind *"I bypassed existing Log-in page and direct very fist request to my home.xhtml page"*. The mistake is there.

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC. I have done it with web.xml
 
<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/views/home.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the way I have set the base URL. It was work fine when change supervisors notation

> base href="#{homeController.baseUrl}"

to

> base href="#{request.contextPath}/"

Thanks a lot for  BalusC & every one.